# Laravel blade remove string limit

Tags: php, laravel

How can I remove the string limit when I display it in the blade?

I tried `str_limit($details, $limit = -1)` and `str_limit($details, $limit = 1000000)`

But still limiting the string when displayed.

**EDIT**

Controller

```
$announcement = DB::table('announcement')
            ->where([
                    'status' => 1,
                    'delete' => 0,
                ])
            ->where('display_date', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->leftJoin('users','announcement.user_id','=','users.id')
            ->leftJoin('user_details','users.user_details_id','=','user_details.id')
            ->orderBy('display_date', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('announcement.created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();

$data['announcement'] = $announcement;

return view( $this->viewpath . 'index' )->with( $data );
```

BLADE

```
@foreach($announcement as $index => $val)
  <div class="a_body">
     <h3 class="a_title">{{ $val->announcement_title }}</h3>
     <div class="a_details">{{ $val->announcement_details}}</div>
     <div class="a_posted">Posted Date: {{$val->display_date}}</div>
     <div class="a_created">By:{{ $val->first_name }} {{ $val->last_name }}</div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Negative value will count from the end of the string. Did you try 0 or null?

Comment: @thefallen when I put 0 no string display at all then if `null` no effect still the same

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but if you don't want a limit then why are you using `str_limit`?

Comment: ^^ just don't use str_limit ?

Comment: Are you actually passing `$limit = -1`, or are you passing `str_limit($details, 1000000)`? You don't need to pass the `$limit` variable in.

Comment: laravel automatically limit the string display even I dont use str_limit

Comment: It shouldn't limit the string. Can you show the blade code and what you're passing in?

Comment: @aynber done edit.

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization limiting a string could have many reasons. First, check if database table stores the entire string. Second, check if you have added any `overflow:hidden` css property to any divs in your blade.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely to do with the database rather than Laravel. Laravel does not limit the string unless you use `str_limit`, so removing this code is a good start.

If your string is being limited, then check that the database is storing your full string in the first place. If your database code is using `VARCHAR`, you may be limiting your strings to the default `255` character length. Changing this to `TEXT` would let you store up to ~64k of data.